# Display Problems

Tags: video, display

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (Guest) in VMWare WS 7.1.2 on Windows 7 64-bit Host.
I have VMWare Tools installed properly and have been using them for years.
I have unchecked 3D Acceleration -- never have used this.
I am running MATE but the problem persists when I change (to and from) xfce, gnome, mate a-- and back again

I have been using this for a couple of years without any graphics issues.

After an Ubuntu update (typical) -- my video is corrupt and will not refresh correctly.

As you may be able to tell from the image attached -- my desktop icons are "mirrored" and when I open a terminal window (for instance) -- sometimes -- the window appears multiple times.  Of course, only one is the real image -- it seems to be a refresh problem.

I do not have enough reputation points to post an image.  Geez what a load of @#%#$$%.

Does anyone know how to fix this ?

Comment: Have you considered upgrading VMWare WS?  Upload image to any image hosting sites, and add the link.

Comment: It seems to be a refresh problem.  When I move an active window around the screen the "older" images "erase" and my icons (for instance) are in the correct location.  

I like to use 1280 x 800 resolution on my virtual machines -- however -- now I do not have a refresh rate defined for 1280 x 800 -- I only have 0 Hz -- which I do not believe was the only choice before this happened.  

My /etc/X11/xorg.conf file is empty -- I tired to use xrandr but that did not work... I will post an image to a public site if this is not sufficient -- I do not have such an account now